# SQL Server 2019 Launchpad R Script "Permission denied" error

Tags: r, sql-server

(edit by [KarMau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12106944/karmau)): [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/concepts/security?view=sql-server-2017#identity-mapping) is the explanation why my client sa login has no access to c:\temp: "Launchpad maps the identity of the calling user to a worker account... Each individual worker account is restricted to its own folder, and cannot access files in folders above its own level."

Following the tutorial "[Lesson 1: Explore and visualize the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/sqldev-explore-and-visualize-the-data?v)" I got an error. At

```
mainDir <- ''C:\\temp\\plots''  
dir.create(mainDir, recursive = TRUE, showWarnings = FALSE)
```

was thrown `Permission denied`.

I am running SQL Server 2019 Preview on Windows 10. After searching some time for a solution I found the R command getwd() which leads me to `C:\\Data\\SQLServer\\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\ExtensibilityData\\Appcontainer1`, a sobfolder of  my SQL Server data folder.
There and only there my code was successful to create files. I repeat: only in the subfolder Appcontainer1. There is an unknown user only identified by the SID S-1-15...

Sorry, but I need at least 10 reputation to post images... [please look here](https://i.postimg.cc/3R5WB8PV/screenshot01.png)

My questions:

1. Is SQL Server 2019 running R code in a sandbox?
2. Are there other solutions to work around this problem?

The complete T-SQL Script:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RPlotHist]  
    AS  
    BEGIN  
      SET NOCOUNT ON;  
      DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) =  
      N'SELECT cast(tipped as int) as tipped, tip_amount, fare_amount FROM [dbo].[nyctaxi_sample]'  
      EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script @language = N'R',  
      @script = N'  
       # Set output directory for files and check for existing files with same names   
        mainDir <- ''C:\\temp\\plots''  
        dir.create(mainDir, recursive = TRUE, showWarnings = FALSE)  
        setwd(mainDir);  
        print("Creating output plot files:", quote=FALSE)

        # Open a jpeg file and output histogram of tipped variable in that file.  
        dest_filename = tempfile(pattern = ''rHistogram_Tipped_'', tmpdir = mainDir)  
        dest_filename = paste(dest_filename, ''.jpg'',sep="")  
        print(dest_filename, quote=FALSE);  
        jpeg(filename=dest_filename);  
        hist(InputDataSet$tipped, col = ''lightgreen'', xlab=''Tipped'',   
            ylab = ''Counts'', main = ''Histogram, Tipped'');  
         dev.off();  

        # Open a pdf file and output histograms of tip amount and fare amount.   
        # Outputs two plots in one row  
        dest_filename = tempfile(pattern = ''rHistograms_Tip_and_Fare_Amount_'', tmpdir = mainDir)  
        dest_filename = paste(dest_filename, ''.pdf'',sep="")  
        print(dest_filename, quote=FALSE);  
        pdf(file=dest_filename, height=4, width=7);  
        par(mfrow=c(1,2));  
        hist(InputDataSet$tip_amount, col = ''lightgreen'',   
            xlab=''Tip amount ($)'',   
            ylab = ''Counts'',   
            main = ''Histogram, Tip amount'', xlim = c(0,40), 100);  
        hist(InputDataSet$fare_amount, col = ''lightgreen'',   
            xlab=''Fare amount ($)'',   
            ylab = ''Counts'',   
            main = ''Histogram,   
            Fare amount'',   
            xlim = c(0,100), 100);  
       dev.off();  

        # Open a pdf file and output an xyplot of tip amount vs. fare amount using lattice;  
        # Only 10,000 sampled observations are plotted here, otherwise file is large.  
        dest_filename = tempfile(pattern = ''rXYPlots_Tip_vs_Fare_Amount_'', tmpdir = mainDir)  
        dest_filename = paste(dest_filename, ''.pdf'',sep="")  
        print(dest_filename, quote=FALSE);  
        pdf(file=dest_filename, height=4, width=4);  
        plot(tip_amount ~ fare_amount,   
            data = InputDataSet[sample(nrow(InputDataSet), 10000), ],   
            ylim = c(0,50),   
            xlim = c(0,150),   
            cex=.5,   
            pch=19,   
            col=''darkgreen'',    
            main = ''Tip amount by Fare amount'',   
            xlab=''Fare Amount ($)'',   
            ylab = ''Tip Amount ($)'');   
        dev.off();',  
     @input_data_1 = @query  
     END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSSQL Server is typically run as a service on Windows under a special user that likely has restricted access to `C:\\temp\\plots`.  To change the user, open the Services app on Windows 10, find the SQL Server service.  Right click, properties, Log On tab, change the account to someone who as access to that location.

Comment: It should be the "SQL Server Launchpad (SQLEXPRESS)" service. The account is "NT Service\MSSQLLaunchpad$SQLEXPRESS". One of my attempts was to give this account (and everyone) full rights to c:\temp. No chance.

Comment: well, that's different than changing the service to run as a different user, but reading through more of the documentation, the file permissions might be based on which user you are using to log into the Sql Server with.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/security/create-a-login-for-sqlrusergroup?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thank you. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/concepts/security?view=sql-server-2017#identity-mapping) is the explanation why my client sa login has no access to c:\temp.